# Typescript odd behaviour extending Number

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype, ecmascript-5

I am extending Number object, so there will be a function toKM() which convert the distance (given in meters) to Kilometers.

When I use the following syntax (which IMO is the default for TypeScript), function is not working.

```js
interface Number {
  toKM(): number
}

Number.prototype.toKM = () => {
  return this / 1000
}

let alfa = 3456
document.write(alfa.toKM())
```

When I use the "traditional" form:

```js
interface Number {
  toKM(): number
}

Number.prototype.toKM = function() {
  return this / 1000
}

let alfa = 3456
document.write(alfa.toKM())
```

Is there a special case that the new syntax is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an arrow function Typescript  will capture this from the declaration context, your code is compiled to this if you target below es6:

```
var _this = this;
Number.prototype.toKM = function () {
    return _this / 1000;
};
```

Arrow functions would not have worked event if you were to use pure JS (es2015 or above) because their behavior would be equivalent to the JS above.

You need to use a regular function and specify the type of `this`

```
Number.prototype.toKM = function(this: number) {
  return this / 1000
}
```

Comment: This is not just a typescript thing if you compile it to es6 and use real arrow functions you will get the same thing.

Comment: @NitzanTomer you are right, I was in TS mode and didn't think about JS, added the clarification

Comment: @NitzanTomer TSC is compiling the code with "target": "es6".

Comment: @ΣτρατήςΧριστοδούλου If you target es6 the behavior is the same, this is captured from the declaration context (the behavior is equivalent to the es5 version above).

Comment: @ΣτρατήςΧριστοδούλου this answer is correct, you can only use the `function() { ... }` in this scenario, as the arrow function will save the context of `this`. It's irrelevant if you're compiling it to `es5` or `es6`

Comment: @NitzanTomer i also think that this answer is correct!
My "upvote" still doesn't count because my reputation is at 13 :)

Comment: So @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thank you for the answer!!! (i can't vote for the answer yet)

Comment: @ΣτρατήςΧριστοδούλου You are welcomed, I think you can still mark as answered (the tick by the question), so other people know the answer is correct

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks again. I just did it (both of them)